# Changing the order of $\lim$ and $\sup$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $f_n:X\to [0,1]$ where $X$ is some arbitrary set. Suppose that 
$$
  f_n(x)\geq f_{n+1}(x)
$$
for all $x\in X$ and all $n = 0,1,2,\dots$ so there exists $\lim_n f_n(x)$ point-wise, let's call it $f(x)$.

Define $f^*_n:=\sup\limits_{x\in X}f_n(x)$, $f^*:=\sup\limits_{x\in X}f(x)$ and $\hat f:= \lim\limits_n f^*_n$. I wonder when $f^* = \hat f$, i.e.
$$
  \lim\limits_n \sup\limits_{x\in X}f_n(x) = \sup\limits_{x\in X}\lim\limits_n f_n(x).
$$

I was googling the topic, but strangely have not found any information, strangely because I expected it to be available as for changing the order of limits or of integration.

Some simple facts: $\hat f\geq f^*$ and the reverse is true at least when $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$. This does not hold in general, e.g. when $f_n = 1_{[n,\infty)}$.

I would appreciate any other ideas that you can advise me. Also related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169517/fixpoint-of-monotone-operators). A similar question was asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83822/does-lim-n-to-infty-sup-x-in-x-f-nx-sup-x-in-x-lim-n-to-in?rq=1).

Comment: Sorry, forget my comments. I was trying to be helpful without properly thinking.

Comment: @MattN: done: fogotten

Comment: I think that convergence of minima/maxima is related to $\Gamma$-convergence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given $\epsilon>0$, let $E_n=\{x\in X: f_n(x)\ge \hat f-\epsilon\}$ and $E^*=\{x\in X: f(x)\ge \hat f-\epsilon\}$. We know that the sets $E_n$ are nonempty and nested: $E_{n+1}\subset E_n$. We would like to show that $E^*$ is nonempty. Since $f_n$ decreases to $f^*$ pointwise, it follows that $E^*=\bigcap E_n$.

So the problem becomes: how do we show that a nested sequence of nonempty sets has nonempty intersection? I know three ways:

- $E_1$ has finite measure and the measures of $E_n$ are bounded from below by $c>0$.
- each $E_n$ is compact
- $X$ is complete, each $E_n$ is closed, and $\mathrm{diam}\, E_n\to 0$.

Comment: Thank you, did you mean that $f^*(x)$ is $f(x)$?

Comment: @Ilya Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is equivalent to asking if 
$$\begin{equation}\inf_n \sup_x f_n(x) = \sup_x \inf_n f_n(x) \tag{*}\end{equation}.$$

This question is the subject of *minimax theorems*, e.g. [Sion's minimax theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sion%27s_minimax_theorem). Minimax theorems are applied frequently in game theory.

Generally speaking, (*) is true if $n \mapsto f_n(x)$ is (quasi-)concave and $x \mapsto f_n(x)$ is (quasi-)convex. You will also need some sort of (semi-)continuity and a "nice" structure for the sets in the infimum and supremum (for instance $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f_n(x) = \frac1n |g(x)|$).